# C++ Warning pop up help when trying to generate random numbers?

Tags: c++

Trying to write a code to generate the random velocities for x, y, and z constraining these velocities to the equation x^2+y^2+z^2 <= 200. I am having the warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith] warning pop up? Any help would be greatly appreciated, new C++ coding student

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int N , x, y, z, vt, pow;
    printf("Enter the number of particles: \n");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    random [N];

    printf("The velocity of the particles are\nx: y: z:\n");
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++){
        // the square is N x N, so you want two numbers from 0 to N-1
        int x = rand() % vt;
        int y = rand() % vt;
        int z = rand() % vt;
        vt = 200 - ( pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)+pow(z,2));

        printf("%d %d %d\n", x, y, z);

    }
}
```

Comment: `vt` is uninitialized when first used in `int x = rand() % vt;`.

Comment: `random [N];` doesn't seem like valid c++.

Comment: It looks like you may be taking inspiration from a C guide or tutorial. C++ and C are different languages. In C++, the math header is `#include <cmath>` and `pow` is in the namespace `std`, it should be `std::pow(x, 2)`.

Comment: The warning should mention a file and line number.

Comment: Sidenote: the `pow` function is designed to handle really nasty smurf like e to the power of pi. Using it to square a number, especially an `int` is often massive overkill. A particular implementation could have a non-standard faster path for squares of integers, but it's best if you don't count on it and just multiply the number by itself. Plus because `pow` operates on floating point numbers, you find yourself with odd answers due to imprecision and truncation.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems to be that this code doesn't look like it was written by a single person, piece by piece. It's like a weird mishmash of bits and pieces copied from somewhere else and the pieces don't fit.

Let's go through it.

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

That's the C++ version of the `<stdlib.h>` C header. Not too weird.

```
#include <iostream>
```

The `<iostream>` header for C++ stream-based I/O. Good.

```
#include <math.h>
```

That's the C header for basic math functions. The C++ version is called `<cmath>`. Where did you get that from?

```
int main(){
```

A typical C++ `main` function.

```
    int N , x, y, z, vt, pow;
```

Here you predeclare a bunch of variables long before they're used. This is (still) somewhat common in C, but not idiomatic C++. In C++ you'd probably declare your variables closer to where they're used.

Another weird thing: One of your variables is called `pow`, which is also the name of a standard function.

```
    printf("Enter the number of particles: \n");
    scanf("%d", &N);
```

Here you're calling `printf` / `scanf`, which are standard C functions for output/input, without including their proper header, which is `<stdio.h>`. But you're ostensibly writing C++, so that should be `<cstdio>` and `std::printf` / `std::scanf` instead, except in C++ you'd typically use `std::cout` and `std::cin`. Which are declared in `<iostream>`, which you included but didn't use.

If you're going to use `scanf` at all (which I don't recommend), you should always check its return value to make sure it was successful: `if (scanf("%d", &N) != 1) { /* error */ }`.

```
    random [N];
```

This line makes no sense. You're indexing into an array called `random`, which doesn't exist (no variable called `random` was declared in your code). The only reason you're not getting an error about that is that on some platforms there is a (non-standard) function called `random`, but treating a function as an array doesn't really make sense either. This is probably the source of the warning you're asking about.

```
    printf("The velocity of the particles are\nx: y: z:\n");

    srand(time(NULL));
```

You included `<cstdlib>`, so that should be `std::srand`, not `srand`. `time` isn't declared at all; you forgot to include `<ctime>` (or `<time.h>`, but you should really figure out if you're programming in C++ or C).

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++){
```

Not a hard error, but seeing a loop from `0` to `<= N` raises a red flag. Usually it's `1` with `<=` or `0` with `<`. The way you're doing it this loop iterates `N+1` times.

```
        // the square is N x N, so you want two numbers from 0 to N-1
        int x = rand() % vt;
        int y = rand() % vt;
        int z = rand() % vt;
```

That should be `std::rand`, not `rand`.

`vt` is uninitialized here (during the first iteration).

Also, you're creating new local variables `x`, `y`, `z` that only exist within the loop (and shadow the outer variables of the same name declared at the beginning of `main`).

```
        vt = 200 - ( pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)+pow(z,2));
```

This line is a hard error: You're trying to call `pow` as a function, but it is a local variable declared as an `int` (see the beginning of `main`).

```
        printf("%d %d %d\n", x, y, z);
    }
}
```

Having reached the end of `main` we never used the `x`, `y`, `z` variables declared at the beginning. `N` was used somewhat correctly. `vt` was used incorrectly (before it was initialized). `pow` was just an error: It was only used as a function, not a variable.

Comment: I use the teacher power point examples and instructions to bas my code off of. That's prob why its weird then.

Comment: I just attached the code below, I attempted to convert everything purely to c++, only thing now is saying floating point exception.

Comment: @DaltonZarko That usually means you divided by zero.

Comment: floating point exceptions can also happen if you modulo-by-zero (e.g. `int x = std::rand() % 0;`)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int N , x, y, z, vt;
    cout << "Enter the number of particles: \n";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "The velocity of the particles are\nx: y: z:\n";
    std::srand(time(NULL));
         for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++){

        int x = std::rand() % vt;
        int y = std::rand() % vt;
        int z = std::rand() % vt;
        vt = 200 - ( std::pow(x,2)+std::pow(y,2)+std::pow(z,2));

       cout << "%d" << x << " %d" << y << " %d\n" << z;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little commentary to this answer?  A pure code-dump isn't very informative on its own.

Comment: This code was going off of the other users suggestion.

Comment: I attempted to convert everything purely to c++, only thing now is saying floating point exception.